# Powershell doesn't do write-host on Get request

Tags: powershell

I am doing my first script that is pulling data from our customer database through an API.

The problem is, that I have put different write-host sections throughout for better logging and tracking, yet the get requests display all the json data, I did not explicitly ask powershell to do this that I am aware of.

This is all that is in my function.. and it does work, but I keep seeing the get request displayedg, when all I want is my write-host.

```
Write-Host "Fetching Customer data for " + $CustomerID

$customer = Invoke-WebRequest $ApiURL | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Is there a way to not show it?

Comment: I think you're really only interested in the `.Content` property inside the output of `Invoke-WebRequest`. Try `$customer = (Invoke-WebRequest $ApiURL).Content | ConvertFrom-Json `

Comment: You mean you see a progress bar on the top while the request is executing? `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`

Comment: @Theo it is the display in the console that I am wanting to not see.

Comment: Well... on my system (Win 10, PS 5.1) I'm not getting any output since it is captured in the `$customer` variable. Explain what output you get, because this is not clear.

Comment: A screenshot might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Write-Output "Fetching Customer data for $CustomerID"
$customer = Invoke-WebRequest $ApiURL | ConvertFrom-Json
```

One thing I noticed is you assigned the $customer variable but you're printing $CustomerID on your write host. Are you trying to get only that property out of the data? If so then I would pipe once more like this.

```
$customer = Invoke-WebRequest $ApiURL | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CustomerID
```

Then on your output:

```
Write-Output "Fetching Customer data for $customer"
```

**

> In addition Write-Host is buggy at best under many circumstances, I
> would strongly suggest to replace with Write-Output whenever possible.

**